# jquery validation engine and asp.net ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jQuery validation engine to validate my signup asp.net form

how can I use ajax function to check username?

there are some codes in plugin

```
"ajaxUserCall": {
    "url": "ajaxValidateFieldUser",
    // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
    "extraData": "name=eric",
        "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
        "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
},
    "ajaxUserCallPhp": {
    "url": "phpajax/ajaxValidateFieldUser.php",
    // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
    "extraData": "name=eric",
    // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
    "alertTextOk": "* This username is available",
        "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
        "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
},
    "ajaxNameCall": {
    // remote json service location
    "url": "ajaxValidateFieldName",
    // error
    "alertText": "* This name is already taken",
    // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
    "alertTextOk": "* This name is available",
    // speaks by itself
    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
},
    "ajaxNameCallPhp": {
    // remote json service location
    "url": "phpajax/ajaxValidateFieldName.php",
    // error
    "alertText": "* This name is already taken",
    // speaks by itself
    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
},
```

assuming

```vb
  <WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function getAvailability(ByVal Username As String) As String

    If Username = "rrrrrr" Then
        Return 1
    Else
        Return 0

    End If

End Function
```

method is placed in same page as signup form signup.aspx
and script located in js folder ,how should i change script ?